# Sending an array of integers to a selectpicker value from AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, bootstrap-selectpicker

Upon a model popup, I need a selectpicker dropdown to be pre-populated with values. I have tested that this method works by manually entering some IDs, like so:

```
$("#listPhones").selectpicker('val', [1,5]);
$("#listPhones").selectpicker("refresh");
```

My [WebMethod] function in the code behind returns a string like so:

```
1,5
```

And I am plugging this in using data.d, so the final output is:

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/default.aspx/GetRespIds",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ Responders: editPhonetbxValue }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        //alert(data.d);
                        $("#listPhones").selectpicker('val', [data.d]);
                        $("#listPhones").selectpicker("refresh");
                    }
                });
```

Entering the 1,5 value manually works and selects the items in the dropdown as expected, but parsing it through the AJAX data.d variable does not - can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What does alert(data.d) shows??

Comment: @apomene It show's the value as expected: 1,5
Edit: I even placed characters either side to ensure no white space etc.

Comment: I guess it is '1,5' which is a string thus it must be splitted and parsed to become an int array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you method return a string and you want an array you must use split. Also you have to parse it to int. Try like:

```
$("#listPhones").selectpicker('val', data.d.split(',').map(Number));
```

Comment: Ah, I see now that I had to convert it back to int. Thank you very much!!